# How to sample $N$ Bernoulli random variables given a fixed number of successes ahead of time without collisions?

Tags: sampling, multinomial-distribution, causality, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose that I have $N$ units and that each unit has a probability of being treated, $p_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, N$. Treatment is indicated as $1$ and non-treatment is $0$. Suppose that $p_i$ turns out to be very small for most $i$, so that on average I do not get a whole lot of treated samples if I sample each unit with probability $p_i$, then report if I got $1$ or $0$.

Suppose that I want to ensure that a certain amount of units gets treated, say $m$.

This looks like a multinomial sampling scheme, I am wondering if the correct way to do this is to renormalize all the probabilities $p_1, \ldots, p_N$ and then use a multinomial sampler?

Will I run into an issue of collisions where the same unit gets treated again and again?

Comment: what do you mean by "ensure"? Are you drawing these Bernoulli's sequentially, and then stopping when you have $m$ total treatments?

Comment: That is actually what I was hoping to ask. Are there procedures that do it correctly? Would sequentially drawing them be a correct method? Are there any sources or samplers you could point me to?

Comment: You were hoping to ask me what you mean by "ensure"? Or you were wondering if you should draw sequentially with a stopping criterion? I don't know enough about what you're trying to do to tell you.

Comment: Are you trying to just keep sampling until you see $m$ successes? (Is this without replacement?) Or are you trying to specify some number of observations to take up front that will give some probability of getting at least $m$ successes in the resulting sample?

Comment: I want to fix the number of successes to be $m$. In other words, if I have a binary vector of length $N$, I want $m$ of the entries of the vector to be $1$ and $N-m$ to be $0$. Each of these units have an underlying probability $p_i$ such that $\sum p_i = 1$.

Comment: You can adapt the method from https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/329157/11887